# .htcaccess in Apache not working

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I enabled mod_rewrite and want to redirect one of my local virtual host websites to google.com for practice.

I created an .htcaccess file in my virtual directory (/var/www/example.com/.htcaccess) and gave permissions to .htcaccess by adding the following code to my virtual host's (example.com) config in /sites-available/.

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
 </Directory>
```

I am now attempting to use mod_rewrite by adding code to the .htcaccess file but have had no success thus far. Is there any way to check if .htcaccess is working? If it is, how do I redirect using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an typo. Normally the file name is `.htaccess`, not `.htcaccess`.

An other option is to set the file-name to you "personal style", like:

```
 AccessFileName .htcaccess
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html